# Login with insert log activity in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, datetime, authentication, insert

Table : (kode_user, kode_type, username, password, email, log_aktivitas)

Model

```
function cek_login($username, $password) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', md5($password));

    $query = $this->db->get($this->tabel_name, 1);
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

How do when I do login, log_aktivitas table filled automatically insert or update the time same when I do a login.

table log_aktivitas type (datetime).
Please help, thank you for your participation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not miss understood your question, you're trying to auto update log_aktivitas column value when login occured. You can achieve this by modifying your model. Before querying to DB you should update the log_aktivitas.

```
function cek_login($username, $password) {

    //Where statement
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', md5($password));

    //update log_aktivitas
    $data = array(
           'log_aktivitas' => "YOUR LOG_AKTIVITAS VALUE HERE"
        );
    $this->db->update($this->tabel_name,$data);

    //selecting data
    $this->db->select('*');


    $query = $this->db->get($this->tabel_name, 1);
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
       return $query->row_array();
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried changing my model according to what you suggest, but in the table  log _aktivitas no change.